# How to align equal signs of a set of equations including words such that all the equations together are in the center of an indented paragraph too

Tags: equations, margins

I have a book including an indented paragraph wherein I want to put three consequent eqations including words. I like to align their = sign also I like to put the set of three equations at the center of the indented paragraph. Do you know how to do that?

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\chapter{my paragraph including equations}
This paragraph has 2.25 inch indentation with respect to the original .5 
inch margin left defined by geometry.
I have a sequence of equations and I like them to be aligned so that their 
equal signs "= "are aligned but I like them to be located at the center of 
this indented paragraph too.
Also for some numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we get:
\begin{center}
$a=b+c+99999999999999999$,\\
$c=a+56$ implies $a+9$ is good,\\
$b=a$ or $c$ is good imply $b$ needs to be carefule.
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the `align*` environment from the `amsmath` package fit your requirement?

Comment: My equations include words too. I do not know how to use align* with these equations. I like to preserve the main font in the words of equations too.

Comment: What's the purpose of `adjustwidth` for the whole text?

Comment: @egreg: to get white margin for the reader to put notes

Comment: @Aria Then use `geometry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in,
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\chapter{my paragraph including equations}
This paragraph has 2.25 inch indentation with respect to the original .5
inch margin left defined by geometry.
I have a sequence of equations and I like them to be aligned so that their
equal signs "= "are aligned but I like them to be located at the center of
this indented paragraph too.
Also for some numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we get:
    \begin{align*}
a & =b+c+99999999999999999,\\
c & =a+56 \text{ implies } a+9 \text{ is good,}\\
b & =a \text{ or } c \text{is good imply } b {needs to be carefule.}
    \end{align*}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

- newer put `\chapter` inside `adjustwidth`, rather redefine `\chapter` style
- for text inside equations use `\text` from `amsmath` package`

if you persist with your approach to formatting your document, than remove `%` before `\begind{adjustwidth}` and `\end{adjustwidth}` in above MWE (Minimal Working Example).

and you will obtain

[image]

Comment: I need that \begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}. I can not delete that adjustwidth. That is my indentation for my paragraph.

Comment: @Aria put it back in it should work P.S. watch out for an extra \text needed on last line needs to be `b & =a \text{ or } c \text{ is good imply } b \text{ needs to be carefule.}` also check speeling

Comment: @Aria, you can stick with your (to my opinion  wrong)  approach to formatting document,. Just remove `%` before `\begind{adjustwidth}` and `\end{adjustwidth}`. If your complete document is inside `adjustwidth` environment, it is better and correct to accordingly adjust your `geometry` settings.

Comment: @Zarko : Thank you so much. I also thank KJO for useful comments.

Comment: @Aria, you are welcome. See edited answer (i add picture how will look your chapter formatting).